# Pgfplots power of ten label stuck on wrong side of the chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a simple chart that has a secondary Y axis with really small numbers. Here's the code that produces the chart:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick=data,
        axis y line*=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        xlabel=\textbf{m},
        ylabel=\textbf{p\textsubscript{m}},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.3
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (10, 0.21)
        (30, 0.22)
        (50, 0.24)
        (70, 0.19)
        (90, 0.1)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        axis line style={-},
        ymin=0, ymax=0.0122
    ]
    \addplot [ultra thick, orange, stack plots=false,line join=round,smooth] coordinates {
        (10, 0.0067)
        (30, 0.011)
        (50, 0.012)
        (70, 0.0093)
        (90, 0.0049)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the label `*10^-2` that goes with the right-side Y axis of the chart is stuck on the left side and I can't think of what to do. Is there a way to fix this?

Also the picture of what's wrong:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Just add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` (or a higher number) somewhere after loading `pgfplots` package.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Oh, thank you very much! Didn't think it would be that easy... But it is indeed my first LaTeX project. If you'd format that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347615/pgfplots-power-of-ten-label-stuck-on-wrong-side-of-the-chart#comment853379_347615), just add `compat` level 1.3 or higher to the document preamble to get the desired result.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick=data,
        axis y line*=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        xlabel=\textbf{m},
        ylabel=\textbf{p\textsubscript{m}},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.3
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (10, 0.21)
        (30, 0.22)
        (50, 0.24)
        (70, 0.19)
        (90, 0.1)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        axis line style={-},
        ymin=0, ymax=0.0122
    ]
    \addplot [ultra thick, orange, stack plots=false,line join=round,smooth] coordinates {
        (10, 0.0067)
        (30, 0.011)
        (50, 0.012)
        (70, 0.0093)
        (90, 0.0049)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Many thanks. Just for your information: Besides accepting the answer, you should also be able to [upvote answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) by pressing upward pointing arrow above the accept check mark.